# Don't erase background for visual trace in Quartz Composer

Tags: feedback, quartz-composer, compositing

I it possible NOT to clear the background in Quartz Composer? I want to move an image across the screen and keep it visible at the old positions to have some sort of trace effect.

Thanks and regards,
Sebastian Mecklenburg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your rendering inside a `Render In Image` patch, and connect its output to an `Addition` patch.  Connect the output of `Addition` to an `Accumulator` patch, and connect the output of the `Accumulator` patch to the "Background Image" port of the `Addition` patch, to create a feedback loop.  Then connect the `Addition` patch to a `Billboard`.

[image: Image addition feedback loop]

Answer (score 0):

Check 'Enable Feedback Rendering' under the properties for the `Render In Image` patch.

[image]